# validate "sub groups" inside a number using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a SSN input, the rules I need to validate are:

- the 1st group, can only be digits and can't be "000"
- the 2nd group, can only be digits and can't be "00"
- the 3rd group, can only be digits and can't be "0000"
- the whole expression can't be either "000000000" or "111111111" or "333333333" or "123456789"

I came up with this regex validation, but it doesn't look like it's working correctly with these rules, I need help to understand what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated

```
^(?!000)\d{3}(?!00)\d{2}(?!0000)\d{4}(?!000000000|111111111|333333333|123456789)\d{9}$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex for your validation checks:

```bash
^(?!(?:([013])\1{8}|123456789)$|000|\d{3}00|\d{5}0000)\d{9}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VLvhgb/4)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!`: Start lookahead

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `([013])`: Match digit `0` or `1` or `3` in capture group #1
    - `\1{8}`: Match 8 repetitions of same digit captured in group #1
    - `|`: OR
    - `123456789`: Match `123456789`
  - `)`: End non-capture group
  - `$`: End
  - `|`: OR
  - `000`: Match `000`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d{3}00`: Match any 3 digits followed by `00`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d{5}0000`: Match any 5 digits followed by `0000`
- `)`: End negative lookahead
- `\d{9}`: Match 9 digits
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

You can put the negative lookahead at the beginning and that will also now allow all zeroes, so you don't have to add the separate checks like `(?!000)` as the total number of digits is 9.

If you want separate groups, you can capture them.

In short with a capture group for either 1, 3 or 0 and a backreference:

```
^(?!(?:([013])\1{8}|123456789)$)(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyiDVW/1)

**Edit**

If neither of the 3 parts can be only zero, you can write the negative lookaheads like this:

```
^(?!(?:([013])\1{8}|123456789)$)(?!000)\d{3}(?!00)\d{2}(?!0000)\d{4}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!(?:([013])\1{8}|123456789)$)` Assert not 0's 3's or 123456789 to the right
- `(?!000)\d{3}` Match 3 digits if not only zeroes
- `(?!00)\d{2}` Match 2 digits if not only zeroes
- `(?!0000)\d{4}` Match 4 digits if not only zeroes
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF1rpu/1)

Comment: thanks, that is indeed much simpler, however, this wouldn't check if by example, I had one of the groups be filled with "0" right? for example,  0000 74 7021 would pass, correct?

Comment: Shorter one is much easier to read :)

Comment: @Twhite1195 which parts can not be 00? Just some of them? If so, you can use a negative lookahead to assert either the first second or third part is not 000 or 00 or 0000

Comment: @Thefourthbird in theory none of the parts can be just zero, so the 9 digits can't be "000000000", but each group by itself, can't be filled with zero even if the other groups are ok, so, (using 'X' as valid characters) the SSN cannot be 000 XX XXXX, or XXX 00 XXXX,  or XXX XX 0000, or any combination of those, It looks like how anubhava set it, it checks that, it looks like the same structure too

Comment: @Twhite1195 I see what you mean, I have added a version with the separate lookaheads.